# how to project new sets of data onto a pca space in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, projection, pca

I have got a data set with 68 dimensions * 100 observations to create a pca space using matplotlib in python.

Now I have got another set of data (x) with 6 dimensions * 100 observations. Is it possible to project these data onto the pca space created before?

I tried to use pca_space.project(x) to project, but the dimensions of the pca space does not match the new data set, it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think that really makes sense.  The PCA transformation maps from the original data space into the PCA space.  If the original data space is 68 dimensions, the domain of the transformation is 68-dimensional space.  How do you intend the 6-dimensional space to relate to that?

Comment: I would like to show how each variables in the new data set relate to each Principal Components and map them on a 2D graph(PC1 vs PC2). If I do the dot product on each variables in x and the data on each PC, e.g. all observations on first variables on x *. all observations on PC1, will the returning value suitable to map that variable on PC1?

Comment: I think in order to do that you'll need some additional information about how to map the new dimensions to the existing PCA space.  I don't quite get what you mean with that dot product idea.  You can only dot two vectors of the same dimension.  Is the number of dimensions in your new data (6) the same as the number of PCA dimensions?

Comment: The new data will be 6*100 and result (original data matrix in terms of PC) of the PCA will be 68*100. If I take one variable from new data(1*100 vector) and result of PC1 (1*100 vector) and do a dot product of two. This will give me a value, but does this value in terms of PC1?

Comment: I don't think that will be that meaningful, since those two vectors crosscut the data points (i.e., your 1*100 "vector" really includes one element from each of 100 different vectors).  I think you might have better luck asking about this on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Data Science SE](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/), since the real issue here seems to be the conceptual issue of how to use the PCA, not how to program it.

Answer (score 1):

Given 2 random multivariate gaussians:

```
mu_vec1 = np.array([0,0,0])
cov_mat1 = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
class1_sample = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec1, cov_mat1, 20).T
assert class1_sample.shape == (3,20), "The matrix has not the dimensions 3x20"

mu_vec2 = np.array([1,1,1])
cov_mat2 = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
class2_sample = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec2, cov_mat2, 20).T
assert class1_sample.shape == (3,20), "The matrix has not the dimensions 3x20"
```

One example for reducing the 3D space onto a 2D feature subspace using matplotlib would be

```
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA as mlabPCA

mlab_pca = mlabPCA(all_samples.T)

print('PC axes in terms of the measurement axes'\
        ' scaled by the standard deviations:\n',\
          mlab_pca.Wt)

plt.plot(mlab_pca.Y[0:20,0],mlab_pca.Y[0:20,1], 'o', markersize=7,\
        color='blue', alpha=0.5, label='class1')
plt.plot(mlab_pca.Y[20:40,0], mlab_pca.Y[20:40,1], '^', markersize=7,\
        color='red', alpha=0.5, label='class2')

plt.xlabel('x_values')
plt.ylabel('y_values')
plt.xlim([-4,4])
plt.ylim([-4,4])
plt.legend()
plt.title('Transformed samples with class labels from matplotlib.mlab.PCA()')

plt.show()
```

[image]

But note that `mlabPCA` scales the variables to unit variance (standardization). This may or may not be what you want. If you want more control, I suggest using the sckit-learn package:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA as sklearnPCA

sklearn_pca = sklearnPCA(n_components=2)
sklearn_transf = sklearn_pca.fit_transform(all_samples.T)

plt.plot(sklearn_transf[0:20,0],sklearn_transf[0:20,1],\
     'o', markersize=7, color='blue', alpha=0.5, label='class1')
plt.plot(sklearn_transf[20:40,0], sklearn_transf[20:40,1],\
     '^', markersize=7, color='red', alpha=0.5, label='class2')

plt.xlabel('x_values')
plt.ylabel('y_values')
plt.xlim([-4,4])
plt.ylim([-4,4])
plt.legend()
plt.title('Transformed samples with class labels from matplotlib.mlab.PCA()')

plt.show()
```

[image]