# How to project chosen Eigen Faces onto test data using skikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, eigenvector

**Background:**
I want to do face recognition in Python. Earlier, in Matlab, I've implemented face recognition using roughly this code:

```matlab
[EigVec, projec, eigenVal] = myPCA(TrainingDataFaces);
prinComps = [1, 3, 5];
dimensionReduced = TrainingData'*EigVec(:,prinComps);%project it onto the face space to reduce dimension
model = NaiveBayes.fit(dimensionReduced, classesData);
ProjectedTestData = TestData' * EigVec(:,prinComps);%project it onto the face space to reduce dimension  
r = model.predict(ProjectedTestData(1,:));
```

As you can see, I have `EigVec` available, which gives me enough information of how many principal components I can select. I need to choose specific principal components, and I choose `[1,3,5]`.
Then I can multiply the selected principal components with the training data to get a dimension reduced matrix.

**Trying with Skikit-learn:**
On trying to do [the same thing](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_face_recognition.html) with Skikit-learn, I see that although it provides `pca = PCA(n_components=n_components).fit(X_train)`, this only allows specifying the first `n` principal components. But if I use `pca=PCA().fit(X_train)` and then use `eigenfaces = self.pca.components_[[1,3,5], :]`, I can select specific principal components.
**I need to be able to select specific principal components.**

**The problem:**
To project Eigen Faces onto test data, there's this `trainingProjected = pca.transform(trainingData)`. But `pca` contains all the principal components. I want to project only the EigenFaces `[1,3,5]` onto the training data. How do I achieve this? Is my only option to take the raw Eigen Faces array and multiply it manually with the training data? Doesn't Skikit-learn provide any built-in method of doing it?
I noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375359/how-to-project-new-sets-of-data-onto-a-pca-space-in-matplotlib) question has `pca.fit_transform()`, but the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit_transform) don't indicate it could be used the way I want to.

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually just used `np.dot(trainingData, selectedPrincipalComponents.transpose())` instead of `pca.transform(trainingData)`.